# How can I return a Dictionary<string, string> as an IEnumerable<object> which XUnit's MemberData requires

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I'm trying to use xunit's `MemberDataAttribute` to return a list of Key/Values.

For example, like this:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData("ValidCardData")]
public void GivenANumber_Constructor_CreatesANewInstance(NotSureWhatType data)
{
  ..
}
```

And this is how i'm trying to make the actuall data.

```
public static IEnumerable<object> ValidCardData
{
    get
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("Data\\ValidCards.json");
        var cardNumbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(json);

        return cardNumbers
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>(x.Key, x.Value))
            .ToList()
            .Cast<IEnumerable<object>>();
    }
}
```

but it's not working:

> System.InvalidCastExceptionUnable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String[]]'
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're trying to cast each key/value pair of the dictionary to an IEnumerable.**

If `cardNumbers` is a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`, then you can just do this:

```
return cardNumbers.Cast<object>();
```

A dictionary is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>` to begin with, so you just need to type them as objects.

Comment: Precisely, was just typing the same thing. Just use `Cast` instead of `OfType`, the latter has an extra check which is useless because every item in the sequence is an `object`.

Comment: @Blindy True. I usually use `OfType` over `Cast` just because 1) removing nulls is usually a good thing, and 2) I've had `Cast` behave oddly a couple times. In this case, though, `Cast` should be just as good and, as you mentioned, a bit faster.

Comment: One reason to favour Cast over OfType when you don't definitely want the latter is so that Cast can "behave oddly". Sometimes it means you should indeed use OfType, but sometimes it reveals an error that OfType hides and makes harder to find.

Comment: I kept thinking that `Cast<T>` was casting the entire result as the new type, not the _items_ in the result collection.